# Counting items in Django templates

Tags: html, django

Is it possible to tally items being listed as part of the `django` template within the html?

For example, I have a `django` template with the following code snippet in it:

```
<div>
   {% for thing in thing_list %}
      {% if thing.status == "n" %}
         <a>{{ thing.status.count }}</a>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This `django` template displays all of the things in a list, and I can call each attribute of the thing and display it, so I know I have access to all of the fields.

I want to count then number of "things" and display that number as text. My current attempt above isn't working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not something you should do in the *template* in the first place, you should do this in the view. Templates should only encapsulate *render* logic.

Comment: Totally agreed with @WillemVanOnsem but if you need to parse the number of things and the thing is a model just use this one `Thing.objects.filter(status="n").count()`.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos, should I implement this in models.py or views.py? I am just learning `django`, so I'm a bit confused with the structure.

Answer (score 4):

As Willem says, you should do this in the view. Rather than passing a list of all Things and then checking their status in the template with `if`, you should filter your Things when querying them from the database in the first place:

```
thing_list = Thing.objects.filter(status='n')
```

Then you can do just `{{ thing_list.count }}` in the template.